# Parameterization of $a^2 b^2 +b^2 c^2 +c^2 a^2= d^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

It's easy to see that $(ab, bc, ca, d)$ is a Pythagorean quadruple. In order to find all solutions we use the primitive Pythagorean quadruples. That is

$$ \begin{array}  aab= m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2 \\ bc=2(mq+np) \\ ca=2(nq-mp) \\ d=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2 \end{array}$$

Where $m$, $n$, $p$, and $q$ are non-negative integers with greatest common divisor $1$ such that $m + n + p + q$ is odd.

One can easily conclude that

$$ \begin{array}  aa^2= \frac{(m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2)(nq-mp)}{mq+np} \\ b^2= \frac{(m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2)(mq+np)}{nq-mp} \\ c^2=\frac{(mq+np)(nq-mp)}{m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2} \end{array}$$

How can we find all quadruples of $(m, n, p, q)$ that make above relations true?

Comment: Ask a question on another...  It is necessary to solve a system of nonlinear Diophantine equations. Write down the system of the first 3 equations.  I think you can solve, but the formula of the parameterization will be very cumbersome.   Why are you doing this??? What???

Comment: Although I think you can do without the solution of the system .  We can solve this equation.

Comment: Here's a link to the same equation and solutions (2 answers). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537123/diophantine-equation-x2y2y2z2z2x2-n2

Answer (score 1):

For the equation.

$$a^2b^2+c^2b^2+a^2c^2=d^2$$

The solution can be written directly.

$$b=t(tp^2+2kps+ts^2)$$

$$a=kt(p^2-s^2)$$

$$c=2kp(kp+ts)$$

$$d=kt((2k^2+t^2)p^4+6ktsp^3+2(k^2+t^2)p^2s^2+2ktps^3+t^2s^4)$$

Comment: Again! Some parametric forms without explanation!